# How to do Alias with my query...Not Unique Table/Alias

Tags: sql

I searched over the internet but it never works... 
I used different ways in having aliases, 
but still don't work. I just need a clear 
understanding how to do aliases in SQL.

```
SELECT Property_Return.`*`,  
       Property_Return_Subset.`*`,
       Property_Acknowledgement_Subset.`*` , 
       Property.`*`, 
       Property_Acknowledgement.*
FROM Property_Return 
    INNER JOIN Property_Return_Subset
        ON Property_Return_Subset.fkPropertyReturn_Id
           = Property_Return.PropertyReturn_Id
    INNER JOIN Property_Acknowledgement_Subset
        ON Property_Acknowledgement_Subset.parproperty_Id
           = Property_Return_Subset.fkProperty_Id  
    INNER JOIN Property
        ON Property.Property_Id
           = Property_Acknowledgement_Subset.fkProperty_Id  
    INNER JOIN Property_Acknowledgement_Subset
        ON Property_Acknowledgement_Subset.fkPar_Id
           = Property_Acknowledgment.Par_Id;
```

Comment: You're trying to use the same table twice (`Property_Acknowledgement_Subset`) - this is legal (tables can be referenced multiple times) but you have to use aliases (`tablename as alias`) so that it's clear which instance of the table you're referring to elsewhere in your query. However, I believe in this case that, for the second reference, you *intended* to reference the `Property_Acknowledgement` table instead - since it's mentioned in the `SELECT` clause but isn't in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: can you help me how to put aliases and how to use it in actual? I'm quite confused by doing it. And with the FROM Clause, should i put the Property_Acknowledgment? I Just used one table because they are just connected by each other..   But if you have a better idea or maybe a suggestions, it would be better :)

Comment: FROM Property_Return pr
    INNER JOIN Property_Return_Subset prs ON prs.fkPropertyReturn_Id ...